# Как в андроид реализовать обновление страницы?

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

Прочитал статью, что можно через SwipeRefreshLayout, сделал все как по инструкции, но почему-то программа завершается, в Logcat ничего не пишется (первый раз такое вижу).

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".fragments.HomeFragment">

<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textWelcome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/news_recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/gray_white"
                tools:itemCount="1"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_news_cardview" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Код HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

View view;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
TextView welcomeText;
private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefresh;

ArrayList<String> img_ns = new ArrayList<>();
String nowTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    welcomeText = view.findViewById(R.id.textWelcome);
    if ((Integer.parseInt(nowTime) >= 4) && (Integer.parseInt(nowTime) < 12)) {
        welcomeText.setText("Доброе утро!");
    } else if ((Integer.parseInt(nowTime) >= 12) && (Integer.parseInt(nowTime) < 18)) {
        welcomeText.setText("Добрый день!");
    } else if ((Integer.parseInt(nowTime) >= 18) && (Integer.parseInt(nowTime) < 24)) {
        welcomeText.setText("Добрый вечер!");
    } else welcomeText.setText("Доброй ночи!");
    NewsRecyclerView(container);
    return view;
}

public void NewsRecyclerView(@NonNull ViewGroup container) {
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.news_recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext().getApplicationContext());
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(Objects.requireNonNull(JsonDataFromAsset("exampleNews.json")));
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("exampleNews");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject userData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            img_ns.add(userData.getString("image_news"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    NewsAdapter newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(img_ns, HomeFragment.this.getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
}

@Nullable
private String JsonDataFromAsset(String fileName) {
    String json;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = requireContext().getAssets().open(fileName);
        int sizeOfFile = inputStream.available();
        byte[] bufferData = new byte[sizeOfFile];
        inputStream.read(bufferData);
        inputStream.close();
        json = new String(bufferData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSwipeRefresh = view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
    //Настраиваем выполнение OnRefreshListener для данной activity:
    mSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {

            //Останавливаем обновление:
            mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false)
            ;}}, 5000);
}

}
```

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:**
Обновил вот эту часть кода и все заработало, единственное обновление идет бесконечно) Кака его остановить? onRefresh почему-то не работает

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new SwipeRefreshLayout(this.requireContext());
}
```

Comment: У вас довольно много странного и неправильного в коде. Например в onCreate фрагмента разметка ещё не доступна. В методе NewsRecyclerView (имя должно быть с маленькой буквы) переменная view будет null, т.к. onCreateView ещё не завершился. метод onRefresh выглядит странно - вместо запуска задачи по скачиванию данных вы пытаетесь убрать анимацию через 5 секунд. Корневой LinearLayout - лишний. Всю работу со вьюхами перенесите в onViewCreated. Показывайте/скрыайте анимацию прогресса тогда, когда данные загружаете. А в onRefresh - загружайте данные.

Comment: Спасибо большое сейчас попробую, я просто первый раз пишу программу